# How to delete object automatically without exporting them

Tags: c++, oop, raii

I develop a library that provides various APIs for clients. We have multiple restrictions and one of them is that we should avoid exporting classes as much as possible. This is a problem on some platforms when customers use a wide range of compilers which may name mangle differently.

For this reason we provide interfaces to customers (pure virtual) which effectively hide our implementations. We pass objects to the client using factory methods such as `IUtfString* createUtfString()`, which is usually paired with some `destroyUtf8String(IUtfString* string)` function.

At some places we have calls such as `IUtfString* IUtfString::copy()` which is also either paired with a destroy function or a `IUtfString::release()` function.

This works and everything is fine up to now, but it looks so 1990 C to me. It totally avoids RAII and is merely reusing opaque pointers from C. Is there some kind of idiom to have those factory created objects destroyed automatically without having to export large objects? The pimpl idiom might help since it will hide a large part of the UtfString object, but it still forces us to export objects through libraries/dll which we would like to avoid.

We do have boost support internally, but we also avoid exposing those types to the client.

Comment: How do interfaces solve the name-mangling problem?  Names in abstract classes are mangled just like names in concrete classes.

Comment: I might be mistaken about the rationale behind exporting classes. I mostly remember that it was adopted by many programmers

Comment: I do remember that it is a compiler dependency issue

Comment: @Wyzard: an interface can work nicely as a memory layout specification, because it only involves pointers. the linker is not involved. main example is Microsoft's `IUnknown`.

Comment: @Eric: what prevents client code from using smart pointers?

Comment: We support some platforms that may not support boost, such as embedded TVs and esoteric platforms. Basically, we just don't want to write in our user manual "your platform must support boost".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, but if two compilers differ in their name-mangling rules, there's a good chance that they differ in other aspects of the ABI, such as vtable layout.  Virtual function calls produced by one compiler may not be compatible with the vtables in class instances produced by the other compiler.

Comment: @Wyzard: in principle yes, but in practice COM-derived cross platform technologies such as [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/XPCOM) demonstrate and ensure that compilers conform to a common core ABI on each platform.

Comment: What about pimpl idiom with a twist of polymorphism and a simple gc?  Something like: http://ideone.com/Tky2yX is what I usually do.. This way, if the user `forgets` to clean up, it will take care of it when the program ends.. It requires the classes inherit from some base class so you can store all of them in the same gc..

Answer (score 1):

You could try typedef-ing a `shared_ptr<IUtfString>` and then changing your `createUtfString()` function to return an instance that has a custom deleter.

something like

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<IUtfString> UtfString;

/*does nothing now. Designed for code compatibility*/ 
void destroyUtfString( IUtfString* ) {}

UtfString createUtfString( ... ) {
  return boost::shared_ptr<IUtfString>(oldCreateUtfString(),oldDestroyUtfString);
}
```

Comment: This will require the client to link with the same boost version that we have. That is why we try to hide boost from client's eyes.

Comment: @eric, you could always just include the needed header files/class defs in your code. Or even roll your own class based on how shared_ptr is designed (and un-template it too). It *is* in the new standard after all. Also, you could modify your UtfString class to use a shared_ptr for it's heap resources and return copies by value instead of pointers. That might mean you need to change API though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to expose actual C++ classes to client code, just use destructors and copy constructors as usual.  You can still have special factory functions that create instances and return pointers, but the client will call `delete` on those pointers instead of calling special destruction functions, so the client can use the standard smart-pointer classes to avoid leaking resources.

But if you're trying to avoid C++ name-mangling issues, it may be that your library is exposing only `struct`s and `extern "C"` functions, not classes.  This would mean that your library really has a C API even though it's internally implemented using C++, and you can't provide destructors since you can't have an `extern "C"` destructor.  If that's the case, just recognize that you're providing a C API and don't worry about its lack of C++ features.

Answer (score 0):

I have used similar tricks.  The basic idea is you presume virtual function tables are more stable than name mangling is.

Then you export your functions as `extern "C"`.

What I would do is create header-only wrappers that wrap those return values in `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.  And make sure you do not export them.  They call your `extern "C"` exported functions.  (or `boost`, or roll-your-own)

As they are `inline` in headers, they get compiled on "the client's side of the fence".  So versions and mangling do not matter!

This does force clients to `.get()` when calling back into your API: but you can deal with this with more header only wrappers that take smart pointers and `.get()` (or `.release()`) for them.

If you have intrusive reference counting, then the destroyer of your `shared_ptr` can just reduce the intrusive count by one: this makes passing raw pointers in and returning `shared_ptr`s out more practical.